# Check if a dictionary contains any key object with a specific property

Tags: c#, dictionary

I'm wondering if this can be done in C#. I have a `Dictionary<User, Device>()`, where key and value are:

```
public Device {
    public string Id; 
}

public User {
    public string Name;
}
```

I want to know if my dictionary contains any `User` key which `Name` property is equal to `"John"`. Imagine there was something like:

```
myDictionary.ContainsKey(key => key.Name == "John");
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Technically, `bool contains = myDictionary.Keys.Any(key => key.Name == "John");`

Comment: It would have similar (but slightly worse) performance characteristics of a list so the fact that it is a dictionary won't help ("slightly worse" is simply because there is ever so slight overhead when enumerating a dictionary because it constructs a `KeyValuePair<,>` around each element and have to traverse buckets, not a linear list). In short, there is no quick way to obtain that, if you need it you probably need to reorganize your data structures in some way to get a lookup for that object.

Comment: If you had implemented `GetHashCode` and `Equals` on `User`, you could probably just construct a new `User` with the right name and query on that. If you haven't you have no option but to find the exact reference that points to a `User` with that name. In other words, if two distinct `User` instances with the same `Name` value would be "considered equal" in terms of .Equals and .GetHashCode, you could do: `myDictionary.ContainsKey(new User { Name = "John" });`

Comment: Agreed with @LasseVågsætherKarlsen. If you're having to do this, maybe a dictionary isn't the container you're looking for.

Answer (score 3):

With two modifications (ie. pick one that suits your needs) you can do it:

1. You can override `GetHashCode` and `Equals` on `User` to make two distinct `User` instances *equal* if they have the same `Name` value
2. You can provide a `IEqualityComparer<User>` instance to the dictionary, which would have the same effect as point 1, except that the comparison it outside of `User`

#### Option #1: Override GetHashCode and Equals

With this `User` implementation:

```
public class User
{
    public string Name;

    public override int GetHashCode() => Name?.GetHashCode() ?? 0;
    public override bool Equals(object other) => (other as User)?.Name == Name;
}
```

You can query for such a user with this:

```
myDictionary.ContainsKey(new User { Name = "John" });
```

*([DotNetFiddle example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/KY9MmQ))*

#### Option #2: Implement IEqualityComparer

With this class:

```
public class UserEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<User>
{
    public bool Equals(User x, User y) => x?.Name == y?.Name;
    public int GetHashCode(User obj) => obj?.Name?.GetHashCode() ?? 0;
}
```

*(and no changes to `User`, keep it like it were in your question)*

You can construct your dictionary like this:

```
var myDictionary = new Dictionary<User, Device>(new UserEqualityComparer());
```

And then again you can query it like this:

```
myDictionary.ContainsKey(new User { Name = "John" });
```

*([DotNetFiddle example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/aU17zS))*

---

If neither of these are an option, you have linear search which will perform like if it were a collection of `KeyValuePair<User, Device>`, which is exactly what it will be, and this will probably not have the performance characteristics you want.

Answer (score 0):

`Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` "is" an `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>` which means you could do:

```
myDictionary.Any(kvp => kvp.Key.Name == "John");
```

That would be an O(n) operation though.

If you care about the hashmap performance (hence using dictionary?) you could override the `GetHashCode()` and equality of your `User` class, so that `new User { Name = "John" }.Equals(new User { Name = "John" })` would be true, allowing:

```
myDictionary.ContainsKey(new User { Name = "John" });
```

which is O(1)